# What is the most efficient way to project structured data to a std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, projection

Let's say I have the following struct types:

```
struct XStruct {
   int a_value;
   int b_value;
}

struct YStruct {
   int c_value;
   int d_value;
};
```

Now I have the following vector:

```
std::vector<XStruct> m_x_values;
```

And I want to project my data to so that `c_value`s = `b_value`s and `d_value`s = `a_value`s

```
std::vector<YStruct> m_y_values;
```

What's the most efficient way to do this:

Option 1:

```
m_y_values.clear();
m_y_values.reserve(m_x_values.size());

for(auto x : m_x_values)
{
    m_y_values.push_back({x.b_value, x.a_value});
}
```

Option 2:

```
m_y_values.resize(m_x_values.size());
int i = 0;
for(auto x : m_x_values)
{
    m_y_values[i].c_value = x.b_value
    m_y_values[i].d_value = x.a_value;
    ++i;
}
```

Any other suggestion?

Comment: You can directly construct m_y_values with the size equal to m_x_values thus no resize operation is needed

Comment: I will have to go with `reserve` because `resize` will **value-initialize** the new elements first. It's like an unnecessary `=0` for each element.

Comment: Use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`.

Comment: @Nard, since he has no constructor, the resize() won't initialize anything, right? That being said, not having any initialization is a potential for future bugs.

Comment: @AlexisWilke He has no constructors, therefore the compiler will generate the default constructor, copy constructor, copy assignment operator, and also the destructor. (Pre-C++11)

Answer (score 2):

You can create constructor of the second struct like that:

```
struct YStruct {
   explicit YStruct(const &XStruct x_struct)
   : c_value(x_struct.a_value)
   , d_value(x_struct.b_value)
   {};

   int c_value;
   int d_value;
};
```

You will be able to use `y_struct = x_struct` or `YStruct y_struct(x_struct)`.
Then simple copy each element of first vector to second.

Comment: For safety purposes, I'd add an `explicit` keyword for this constructor so people who perform this **conversion** are expected to know that they want to perform this conversion.

Comment: If you can use `y_struct = x_struct;` you can also copy the vectors directly as in `m_y_values = m_x_values;`, right? (unless you add the `explicit`)

Comment: @Nard: Yeah thanks, edited the post. But maybe this structures are supposed to be transparently convertible, so there is no need to use `explicit`.

Comment: @Alexis Wilke: I think so, but there is no guarantee.

Comment: @Heavy Sure but I'd rather be safe than having my users spend sleepless nights debugging an implicit conversion by the compiler.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Assignment between vectors must be of the same type, including template parameters.

Answer (score 1):

the STL algorithm `transform` is suitable for this kind of problems.

```
std::vector<XStruct> x_values = { { 1, 2 }, {3, 4} };
std::vector<YStruct> y_values(x_values.size());

std::transform(x_values.begin(), x_values.end(), y_values.begin(), [](const XStruct& x){
    return YStruct{ x.b_value, x.a_value };
});
```

Or use `vector::emplace_back` to save some `YStruct` construction time, but it will take some time when the vector is being resized.

```
std::vector<XStruct> x_values = { { 1, 2 }, {3, 4} };
std::vector<YStruct> y_values;

for (const auto& x : x_values){
    y_values.emplace_back(YStruct{ x.b_value, x.a_value });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The `emplace_back` must be the most efficient approach, specially if you reserve the right capacity in the vector.

Comment: But you have to pass the arguments without the constructor, i.e. `y_values.emplace_back(x.b_value, x.a_value);`

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` can be initialized using a pair of iterators and this allows using this idiom:

```
std::vector<A> new_vect(old_vect.begin(), old_vect.end());
```

thus by defining a constructor for `Y` accepting a `const X&` as parameter you would be expressing your intention as clearly and concisely as possible, leaving to the library the freedom to do whatever is best to do the operation.

Delegating to a library and hoping that it's doing the best is not a strategy that always wins (not at all, actually) but in case of `std::vector` I'd be reasonably confident that the compiler implementers did all they could to get the operation as fast as possible.

When in doubt (and only if you actually **measured** this operation is a bottleneck for your code and it's not just guessing) then try measuring other approaches and even possibly inspect the machine code generated. It shouldn't be something happening often.

For my experience I'd expect a `reserve` + `push_back` version the worst approach from a performance point of view because compilers today are not smart enough (AFAIK) to detect this pattern. Even assigning each element may be not the fastest way because when you write

```
v[i] = x;
```

and `v` is an `std::vector` a double indirection is needed because a vector contains a pointer to where the data is. In a few cases I've been forced to explicitly use the approach:

```
X* vp = &v[0];
for (int i=0,n=v.size(); i<n; i++) {
    vp[i] = ...
}
```

instead and this freed up registers and speeded up execution measurably because the compiled code was otherwise always assuming that the vector could have been reallocated during the loop thus redoing the two indirection steps at each iteration, even if a reallocation was technically impossible (no external code called at all, just simple operations between integers, everything inlined).